# Probability Challenging Question regarding with limited money to play machine in casino

Tags: probability, statistics

I just take a probability course this month and I find an interesting question that I do not know to solve, as following:

Suppose a casino machine costs \$10 to play game. for the game, you will get nothing with probability 80%, get \$10 with chance 15%, and get \$20 with chance 5%.

```
|      X     |      $-10   |      $10     |      $20    |
|------------|-------------|--------------|-------------|
|      P.    |      0.8    |      0.15    |      0.05   |
```

Question, you have $40 and keep using them until you have no money, what is the chance you will play at least 7 games?

Comment: I think you mean 0.80 for your first probability, not 0.08

Comment: You are right. Thank you. This is my typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

P(play at least  7) = 1 - P(Lose in less than 7)

You can't lose in less than 4 plays

The only way to lose in 4 plays is to have four \$10 losses in a row
$$P(4) =(0.8)^4$$

You can't lose in 5 plays

The only way to lose in 6 plays is to have one \$10 win and five \$10 losses. your last play must be a loss but the single win could occur in any of the first 5 plays

$$ P(6) = 5(0.8)^5(0.15)$$

Can you take it from there ?

Comment: Thank you @WW1 . I get the hint